# What is the difference between deploying to com+/MTS using regsvr32?

Tags: vb6, asp-classic, com+, mts

We have a legacy VB6 component that was com+/MTS and is used by asp classic. Staff is having trouble with deployment.

Would there be any harm in just using regsvr32 to register the DLL, which will be used by IIS?

Alternatively---I won't touch COM+ with a 10 foot pole--so is there a suitable one line command to register a VB6 component with COM+/MTS using a 11 foot pole?  My google fu is failing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems that I can see:

- With regsvr32 registering your component will run with the same privileges IUSR have. If the component need privileges to connect to the DB or touch the file system, it might fail.
- The component might expect the MTS enviroment (as transactions)

I don't know any suitable command line, being doing it drag-droping the component.